# Help to find the history of my 1900's Armstrong cycle :)

Tags: identify-this-bike, vintage, history

Pretty new to the whole vintage bike thing so would love a bit of help finding the history of the bike I bought in Walthamstow, London, last year.

It's marked to be an Armstrong Cycle, Birmingham, which I have found a lot of information on, but mainly around the 'moth' models and tandems - I can't seem to place the 'Havana'. I'm looking to find the approx date of creation, and perhaps a bit more about it's stand-out features.

Here's some pics. [image][image]

It's got the original seat, bell, lights and 3 gears - it's in great working order.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Charlotte

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Charlotte. At this point your question is quite wide. Can you be more specific about what you want to know? I'm not a vintage bike person, but I can tell you it's definitely *not* from 1900 :-) My guess would be 1960's, from the frame, brakes, and light.

Comment: A classical "English racer" (what they were called in the US).  Eye-catching when the were seen in the 50s and 60s.  Edged out by Italian and French derailleur bikes in the 70s.  That is a nice specimen.

Answer (score 3):

From http://www.bikeforums.net/classic-vintage-bicycles-what-s-worth-appraisals-inquiries/850018-1957-armstrong-havana.html it looks like it could have been made form 1957 to 1961 or later. It looks like it has a 3 speed internal hub gearbox, probably a Sturmy Archer, as it is British made.

Appears that Armstrong was part of a larger group by this stage, and the ealier design approach may have changed a lot.

If you look under where the pedals are (the bottom bracket), there is often a serial number which may contain the year of manufacturer. Or it could be stamped elsewhere on the frame.

Comment: My recollection is that the serial was "elsewhere" -- near the headset or on the seat tube, perhaps.  I'm thinking it could be seen without turning the bike upside-down.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks so much for the all guidance - you've given me a much better idea on what I've got in my hands. I'm actually considering selling this bike on as I'm 5ft 11 and it's a strain on the back! Do you know how much bikes of this origin would be valued you at? You may not, but I thought it was worth an ask!

Answer (score 0):

I have one to, a 1956 Armstrong bike here in the Netherlands.  Its a great bike for work/home rides.[image]

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Rick. Since you're new here, I recommend that you take our [tour] so that you get the most from the site. The [help] is also recommended.

Answer (score -1):

Definitely an Armstrong Havana, late 1950's.  It was my first proper bike.

Comment: Gidday and welcome to SE Bicycles.  Do you recall anything special about the bike?  How was it to ride?  Did anything specific stand out as good or bad?  What did it cost new?  How did you use it?    Your one-line answer does answer the question which is good, but more details would assist OP in doing research.